# stack corruption in coredump ? gcc/c

Tags: gcc, gdb

I am noticing a strange problem when I attempt to use the signal handler to dump global data to a text file and generate the core file. I would expect the data dumped to the file to be the same as that is present in the core file (it is the same global data)

in a header file foo.h

```
extern char buffer[100][80] ; // Hundred records each of length 80 characters
```

in foo.c

```
char buffer[100][80];

.. in a loop ..
snprintf(buffer[i],80,"%s:%d recorded idx = %d\n",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__,i);
```

in signal_handler.c

```
.. in a loop ..
fprintf(..dump data to text file..)
```

The data is dumped to the text file alright. I run the program in gdb and I issue the ABRT signal (the signal I am handling) via kill. In gdb I see

```
gdb) p &buffer[0]
$3 = (char (*)[80]) 0x1002c8970
```

I continue and generate the core file. In the core dump I see

```
(gdb) p &buffer[0]
$2 = (char (*)[80]) 0x1002c9a80
```

the difference between the two positions is 1110.

My question is why do I see this discrepancy in the core file ? Any leads would be appreciated!

Thanks
John

EDIT To clarify, the problem is not in generating the core via GDB 
Full code without signal handlers to isolate the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100
char buffer[100][80];

int main()
{
int i = 0;
int idx = 0;
FILE *fp = NULL;
fp = fopen("test.txt","w");
if (!fp)
    exit(1);

for (i=0; i < 5500; i++) {
    snprintf(buffer[idx],80,"%s:%d idx = %d\n",__FUNCTION__, __LINE__, i);
    idx = ((idx + 1)% MAX);
}
for (i = 0 ; i < MAX; i++)
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer[i]);

fclose(fp);
abort();
return 0;
```

}

The problem is not when I am trying to run in GDB, the problem is that in the core file generated,

gdb) p buffer[0]

$2 "c0 - idx = 54\n", '\0' , "main:20 0x7ef9524"

the buffer is offset by 1110 bytes. I had used GDB to check if the buffer was corrupted. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but what you're doing abuses the signal mechanism.  POSIX defines a long list of functions that it considers "unsafe," and that list includes pretty much everything that does I/O.  It goes on to say that if a signal interrupts the execution an unsafe function and the handler calls an unsafe function, the behavior is undefined.  The most you should be doing in a signal handler is setting a flag to indicate that your dump-to-file operation needs to happen and then returning.  Something in the main program should take care of it.

Comment: The source above is not compilable (missing MAX). If I add '#define MAX 100', it produces expected result: '(gdb) p buffer[0]
$1 = "main:18 idx = 5400\n", '\000' <repeats 60 times>'.

Comment: Updating gdb to the next version seemed to fix the issue. I wonder why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide a stand-alone example. I can explain different address when the core is produced from outside GDB, but not when it is produced from inside GDB.

Here is what I see:

```
$ cat foo.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char buf[100][80];

int main()
{
  sprintf(buf[0], "hello");
  sprintf(buf[1], "hello again");

  abort();
}


$ gcc -g  foo.c -fPIC -pie   # PIE executable so its address can be randomized

$ gdb -q a.out 
Reading symbols from /tmp/a.out...done.
(gdb) r

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7a8ca75 in raise () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64

(gdb) p &buf[0]
$1 = (char (*)[80]) 0x7ffff81ff060
(gdb) sig SIGABRT

Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb) q

$ gdb -q a.out core
Reading symbols from /tmp/a.out...done.
[New Thread 20440]
Core was generated by `/tmp/a.out'.
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x00007ffff7a8ca75 in raise () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64

(gdb) p &buf[0]
$1 = (char (*)[80]) 0x7ffff81ff060  # same address as before
(gdb) q

$ ./a.out
Aborted (core dumped)

$ gdb -q a.out core
Reading symbols from /tmp/a.out...done.
[New Thread 20448]

Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x00007fef9dcb5a75 in raise () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64

(gdb) p &buf[0]
$1 = (char (*)[80]) 0x7fef9e428060  # different address due to ASLR
```

Comment: Thanks !I have edited the post clarifying the problem. I had no idea about pie (or fpie). I dont build with it though.

Comment: I marked this as answer for it is a logical reason for the discrepancy. Although I did not use pie (or fpie) it could be useful for some others to debug. Thanks !